# Scandir scan all sub folder infinetly

Tags: php, arrays, scandir

I have a large piece of code which does a lot of things with folder, files names etc. However, I seemed to have hit an interesting issue.

I am scanning a directory `./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/`

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)); foreach($iterator as $file) echo $file . "<br />";

$iterator = $files;

$files = array();
$webdir = site_url()."/wp-content/uploads/webvideos/";
```

This gives me the first level in the array. Is there an easy way to get it to scan the 1st, 2rd, 3rd etc.

New code

```
 $path = "./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/";

    $webdir = site_url()."/wp-content/uploads/webvideos/";
    $post_title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title());

    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
    $files = array();
    $notAllowedExtension = array('jpg', 'mp3', 'vtr');

    foreach($iterator as $file){

        if(!in_array($file->getExtension(), $notAllowedExtension) && !$file->isDir())
            $files[filemtime($file->getPathname())] = $file->getPathname(); 

    }

    ksort($files);

    echo "<pre>" . print_r($files, true) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: Put the code into a function and call the function recursively when you hit a directory.

Comment: @Rizier123 Is that the most efficient way? A sample code / direction would be great.

Comment: Something like this: `function xy($path){$files = scandir(path); foreach($files as $file){if(is_dir($file)){xy($file);}}}` or you use a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

Comment: @Rizier123 Ok, perfect, I am looking at RecursiveDirectoryIterator solution.  So far, I have this. But working out the rest `$folder = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);`

Comment: Okay if you want to go with `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, then do something like this: `$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)); foreach($iterator as $file) echo $file . "<br />";` to see what you're dealing with.

Comment: @Rizier123  Fantastic. If I wanted to add this into the array, Sorry, I did not post all the code before, updating it now. I am trying it now. Trail and error.

Comment: If you want to add the files into an array, just loop through the iterator and add the files to the array in the loop.

Comment: @Rizier123 Perfect. let me try. Thanks

Comment: @Rizier123 I am confused as to why this would not work. I mean. It is the same concept as scandir. Thanks

Comment: @Rizier123 Still no joy, sorry to be a pain. I am not sure what I am  doing wrong.

Comment: Okay ;) You probably want something like: `$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$notAllowed = array('jpg', 'mp3', 'vtr');
$files = array();

foreach($iterator as $file){
 if(!in_array($file->getExtension(), $notAllowed) && !$file->isDir())
  $files[] = $file->getFilename();
}

print_r($files);`

Comment: @Rizier123, hmm, I tried that. Thanks for the code, but it listed all the files in on my web server. I am going to post the full code. Please one moment.

Comment: You replaced the `"."` in `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` by your path right?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, that is right, Oh dear. let me change that back

Comment: This should do what you want: https://3v4l.org/n6j4Q Just copy the code and use it.

Comment: @Rizier123 Ok, I have updated the code, located above. The code you just made would replay ?? I have tried various parts of the code. No anvil as such yet. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rizier123 On little thing, Example out put `[1350528689] => ./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/folder1/Folder2/V001 - Test Video.mp4`. This `$files` shows up as [1350528689], not as V001 - Test Video.mp4. Thanks immensity

Comment: Then you want to just store the filename, means: `$files[filemtime($file->getPathname())] = $file->getPathname(); ` -> `$files[filemtime($file->getPathname())] = $file->getFilename(); `

Comment: @Rizier123 Fantastic, one last part. The output `[1350528689] => V001 - Test Video.mp4` to make it look like `V001 - Test Video.mp4`. 

The reason is that later on in the COMPLETE code it show up as `[1350528689] => V001 - Test Video.mp4`. However I need it as `V001 - Test Video.mp4`. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: Well that is just the key and the value, so if you output it anywhere and loop through the `$files` array, just only output the value without the key.

Comment: @Rizier123 Right, I can do this !!!.. Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Have a nice Sunday :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Ok, i have been trying. Q: Am I on the right path to use UNSET? I have tried. `[1] => V001-Test-Video.mp4` from this code `$files[] = $file->getFilename(); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114472/discussion-between-rizier123-and-arthor).

Comment: @Rizier123 A quick question please. I am using the code you made, which is great. However I have found something quite strange. If I have 2 files. `File1.mp4` & `File2.mp4` which are identical size. It does not show up in the array. Is there any reason for this. Thank you